# Logic behind reduce and spread function using one line if statement

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

I'm having issues understanding the if statement for this reduce example:

```js
const colors = ['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
console.log(colors);

const distinctColors = colors.reduce(
    (distinct, color) =>
        (distinct.indexOf(color) !== -1) ? 
            distinct : 
            [...distinct, color], []
)

console.log(distinctColors)
```

I'm trying to understand the if statement in pseudocode, and reading this example I keep seeing as follows:

```
If the color found in the distinct array (which is empty)
  return empty array
else
  return contents of array and color added to an empty array
```

I'm I close or way off?

testing repl.it [here](https://repl.it/@paulywill/RealisticThriftyDifference)

Comment: `distinct` is only empty in the first iteration. A more correct explanation would be "If the color is found in the distinct array, return the distinct array. Else return a new array containing the element of the distinct array and the color.". But really, you should just use `const distinctColors = new Set(colors);`.

Comment: Now I would lean toward using a Set `const distinctColors = [...new Set(colors)]'`

Comment: That argument for the initial value is formatted (indented) really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to explain with comments, hope this helps.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
console.log(colors);

const distinctColors = colors.reduce(
    (distinct, color) =>
        (distinct.indexOf(color) !== -1) ? 
        // ----------------^ Turnary to test for presence of current color in the accum []
            distinct : 
        // ----^ It DOES exist, so return the current Accum array    
            [...distinct, color], []
            // ---^ Is DOES NOT exist, return a new array of Accum + Color
            // --------------------^ This initialises a new empty array into the accumulator
)

console.log(distinctColors)
```

Just added this for reference, using a set for this is far more efficient.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
console.log(colors);

const distinctColors = [...new Set(colors)];

console.log(distinctColors)
```

Here is the MDN documentation on Set. [Javascript Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: Does Set grab distinct values by default?

Comment: It does. For more complex objects you will likely use a map combination. In this instance though, you only need pass the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's reducing the array to its unique values. You can read it as:

Set `distinct` to an empty array (2nd parameter to reduce). For each `color` in `colors`, if `color` is in `distinct` (index of !== -1), update `distinct` to `distinct` (no-op) (first ternary branch), else if `color` is not in `distinct`, update `distinct` to `distinct` + `color` (2nd ternary branch).

See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) `reduce` documentation.